# Javascript Asset Download Progress From CDN

Tags: javascript, cdn

I have a web-based app which requires a lot of resources (audio/images/video). Previously I have been hosting everything on the same server and using [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS) to grab all the resources and download them (while showing a nice progress bar).

I am now moving to a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to host all these assets, but need to keep the base web application on my server.

So I have my app on `webapp.com` and all my resources on `cdn.webapp.com` - my question is how do I load all these resources from another domain and view the progress at the same time? Are there libraries that handle this or am I going to need to write up some code to subscribe to the `onload()` function of every asset and only continue when everything is downloaded?

(Thanks to the cross-domain ajax requests I cannot use PreloadJS to download everything anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end (and because no one came to my rescue) I achieved it by doing this:

Images/assets are on `cdn.webapp.com` and were included as usual in the HTML of the page. Javascript would then run and set the div these images were in to have no height. This would still allow the images to load but it would not render them on the page.

I then found a JS library (https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to register callbacks on these images so it would notify me when the images were completely downloaded.